# BeautifulSoup How to exclude elements from HTML

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve all checkboxes with only **edit** in the data-reactid on a form.

Here is the html:

```
<input data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.0.0.$=2fields.0.2.0.0.1.0:$90.0:$=2edit.0.0.0" type="checkbox"/>
<input data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.0.0.$=2fields.0.2.0.0.1.0:$100.0:$=2edit.0.0.0" type="checkbox"/>
<input data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.0.0.$=2fields.0.2.0.0.1.0:$110.0:$=2default.0.0.2.0.0" type="checkbox"/>
<input data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.0.0.$=2fields.0.2.0.0.1.0:$110.0:$=2edit.0.0.0" type="checkbox"/>
...
```

Below is the code I've used to filter the html, but I'm also getting other checkboxes on the form. How do I remove **default** data-reactid's from my selection?

```
chkbox = soup.findAll('input', attrs={"type":"checkbox"})
    for chk in chkbox:
        print(chk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex when filtering by `attrs`, so you could select elements that contains "edit" in the `data-reactid` attribute.

```
soup.findAll("input", attrs={"data-reactid": re.compile(r"edit")})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute = value css selector with * contains operator

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<input data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.0.0.$=2fields.0.2.0.0.1.0:$90.0:$=2edit.0.0.0" type="checkbox"/>
<input data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.0.0.$=2fields.0.2.0.0.1.0:$100.0:$=2edit.0.0.0" type="checkbox"/>
<input data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.0.0.$=2fields.0.2.0.0.1.0:$110.0:$=2default.0.0.2.0.0" type="checkbox"/>
<input data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.0.0.$=2fields.0.2.0.0.1.0:$110.0:$=2edit.0.0.0" type="checkbox"/>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
soup.select('input[data-reactid*=edit][type=checkbox]')
```